# How to take only the integer input from a Sentence?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

I want to get the integers or float or double values from a sentence. As an example - "John has 20 balls, from which 4 are red and 5 are green balls". this will be my input . I want to get the numbers 20 , 4 , 5 from that line. how to do that in java . Please tell me if i can do that using Scanner. I don't want to use bufferedreader.

Comment: You mention floats. Can the numbers be floats?

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to match numbers and collect them from your input:

```
List<String> numbers = Pattern.compile("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")
  .matcher(sentence)
  .results() // stream the MatchResults
  .map(MatchResult::group) // get the entire match
  .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect as a List
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/Snj0wI).

This works for integers and decimals.